# Off the ground the game is at stake

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay, rhyme

> My first part is a pound to take
>   The other part means to forsake 
>   Off the ground the game is at stake 
>   Fly around; make no mistake

Who am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be

> Quidditch

My first part is a pound to take

> A "quid" is British slang for a pound sterling.

The other part means to forsake

> To "ditch" something means to forsake something.

Off the ground the game is at stake

Fly around; make no mistake

> Quidditch is a fictional game in the Harry Potter universe, played flying on broomsticks.